# Box is separating from the search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, liferay

So im working in this page https://www.pacificotest.com.pe/.
- When someone scroll the page, the box that appears when you type "Clinica  "
  move is not absolute, and when I change it to absolute it keep moving anyway.
- Is there any code of css, js or jquery that unify two Classes or ID together, 
  so they dont get far from each other?

[When you scroll down a little bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70VAW.jpg)

[When you scroll top fast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F70L1.jpg)

So the script that i create is this one:

```
<script>
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1) {
                    $('.autocomplete-suggestions').each(function(i,j) {
                        $(this).addClass('fix-searcher'+(i+1));
                    });
                }
            });

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 15) {
                    $('.aui .fix-searcher1').addClass("fixed");
                    $('.aui .fix-searcher1').removeClass("fix-searcher1");
                    $('.aui .fix-searcher2').addClass("fixed2");
                    $('.aui .fix-searcher2').removeClass("fix-searcher2");  
                } else {
                    $('.aui .fix-searcher1').removeClass("fixed");
                    $('.aui .fix-searcher1').addClass("fix-searcher1");
                    $('.aui .fix-searcher2').removeClass("fixed2");
                    $('.aui .fix-searcher2').addClass("fix-searcher2");
                }
            });
        </script>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed{
position: fixed ! important;
top:100px ! important;
}

.fixed2{
position: absolute ! important;
top:430px ! important;
z-index:100 ! important;
}

div.dropdown-menu.flyover {
margin-top: -1px !important;
}

div.portlet-borderless-container div.portlet-body div.news-card div.text .category {
z-index: 0;
}

.fix-searcher1{
position: fixed ! important;
top:140px ! important;
}

.fix-searcher2{
top:490px ! important;
z-index:100 ! important;
}

.aui .autocomplete-suggestions {
margin-top: 0 ! important;
}

.sub-menu-affix {
    background-size: 12px 180%,12px 180%,0, 0 ! important;
}
```

Comment: Please read this: [https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) regarding the use of `!important`. Also, there are several places where you have a space between `!` and `important`. You should remove that space if you really want to use all of those.

Answer (score 0):

### New Approach

Try this instead. Use CSS to position the body content and then simply assign static classes to the suggestion divs.

```js
// here simply assign a static class and we won't be doing any
// listening on window scroll any longer instead we will use
// css to re-position our content.
$(function() {
  $('.autocomplete-suggestions').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('fix-searcher' + (index + 1));
  });
});
```

```css
.au .affix-top + #content {
  margin-top: auto;
}

/* here in the browser 60px worked fine for me, you can play around with the number */
.au .affix + #content {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

/* no need for other .fixed and .fixed2 classes */
.fix-searcher1 {
  top: 140px !important;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}

.fix-searcher2 {
  top: 490px !important;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

### Old Answer

The snapping of the drop-down seems to be causing due to the way top dark-blue banner is getting added and removed from the page.
[site snapshot with top banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9MfV.png)

The scrollTop check that you are conducting to change the class should be equivalent to the height of that banner. Also i would using different class name for adding identifier to search div that way styling and div identification can stay separate. Something like this:

```js
// here if you are using the class just for identification then
// you can add it once on page load and use it for selection later
// which would help avoid any conflict with the style class we will
// use on the suggestion container to position it.
$(function() {
  $('.autocomplete-suggestions').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('js-searcher-' + (index + 1));
  });
});

// here we can change the top offset for the suggestion container
// based on the scrollTop position matching the top emergency banner
// height
$(window).scroll(function() {
  const $searcher1 = $('.aui .js-searcher-1');
  const $searcher2 = $('.aui .js-searcher-2');
  const emergencyBarHeight = 40;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= emergencyBarHeight) {
    $searcher1.removeClass("fix-searcher1").addClass("fixed");
    $searcher2.removeClass("fix-searcher2").addClass("fixed2");
  } else {
    $searcher1.removeClass("fixed").addClass("fix-searcher1");
    $searcher2.removeClass("fixed2").addClass("fix-searcher2");
  }
});
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This code helped me to fix the error that the box cover the search bar on the way up, but it keeps separating when you scroll down.
How can I make one class or ID to stop listening to the global scroll event. When i remove the global scroll event, it fix the box.

Comment: @AlonsoGP did the new approach mentioned in the edited answer work for you?